# Start host for integration test from test base throws not implemented exeption

Tags: asp.net-core, servicestack, integration-testing

```
public class IntegrationTestBase : IDisposable
{
    protected readonly ServiceStackHost appHost;

    public const string BaseUri = "http://localhost:5000/";

    public IntegrationTestBase()
    {
        Licensing.RegisterLicense(
            "license key");
        appHost = new BasicAppHost(typeof(AppHost).GetAssembly())
            {
                ConfigureContainer = container =>
                {
                    //Add your IoC dependencies here
                }
            }
            .Init()
            .Start(BaseUri);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        appHost.Dispose();
    }
}
```

I need to write integration tests and used this code to start a host in order to make tests but it throws not implemented exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Calling `IAppHost.Start(baseUrl)` is only for Self-Hosting AppHost's which launch a server to listen for requests at the specified BaseUrl. `BasicAppHost` is just an In Memory AppHost you can use for Unit tests so you only need to call `Init()` as it doesn't launch anything.

If you're instead looking to [create an Integration Test](http://docs.servicestack.net/testing#integration-testing) then you should inherit from `AppSelfHostBase` instead.

Comment: In order to get AppSelfHostBase which nuget package do I need to install?

Comment: It's in ServiceStack for .NET Framework or ServiceStack.Kestrel for .NET Core